# Android/Spinner: Remove padding to the right of the arrow

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, spinner, padding

I'm using a spinner in a relative layout with a couple of other layout elements (layout-v21):

[image: My spinner]

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="155dp"
android:layout_height="34dp"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textList"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textList"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textList"
android:paddingRight="1dp"/>
```

This sets the distance to where the parent layout ends:

```
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

This sets how close the choice items inside the spinner can get to the left of the arrow (right padding of the text):

```
android:paddingRight="1dp"
```

But is there a way to get rid of (or at least make smaller) the unnecessary space/padding that is to the **right** of the arrow but still within the spinner layout element (so I can then use more space on the left without changing the size of the spinner)?

This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

Edit: Here's the code for the RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity"
android:backgroundTint="#000000"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Comment: Please provide the code from the parent RelativeLayout as well.

Comment: As you have given fixed width android:layout_width="155dp" .Simple increase android:layout_marginStart="5dp" to 10dp/15dp.

Comment: @LuísHenriques I added it to the first post.

Comment: @RohanLodhi Please explain how that would help in my case. `android:layout_marginStart=5dp` controls the distance to the layout element on the left of the spinner, which is the same as  `android:layout_marginLeft=5dp`. Neither changes anything about the padding, only the size of the whole element.

Comment: @Neph android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" in relative layout remove.

Comment: @RohanLodhi Please look at the second image I added, your suggestion removes the padding between the spinner element and the right side of the RelativeLayout, so the padding to the right of the red circle (which marks what I want to remove/decrease in size). It doesn't change anything about the actual inside of the spinner element.

Answer (score 4):

It work for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:backgroundTint="#000000"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"/>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="spinner_style">
        <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
</style>
```

spinner_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@android:color/white" android:startColor="@android:color/white" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="6dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="6dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center|right" android:src="@drawable/ic_spin_down_arrow" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: What exactly does it remove for you? The padding to the right of the arrow but still **inside** the spinner element or the padding to the right of the spinner and with that also **outside** the spinner element? If you can't describe it, you can mark the area on the first image I posted.

Comment: @Neph check now .sorry not saw your second image.

Comment: Ah, you're creating your own style, I see. I'm guessing there's no way to remove the padding on the right then without doing that? Please delete the first part though and just leave the edited part in, it's confusing otherwise. In which folder do I have to put the "spinner_bg.xml" file, into "values" (where "styles.xml" is as well) or "layout-v21" and where can I get the `spinner_bg` and `ic_spin_down_arrow` files from (haven't got them in my "drawable" folder of course).

Comment: spinner_bg.xml in drawable folder and you can use any drop down arrow ,you will get easily get from google or android studio.Please if it work please upvote it.